# can't use request.form.get get the form table contents in flask

Tags: jquery, python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

web page has an form and inner table:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('data.dataupdate',username=current_user.name,tablename=ddatatablename) }}">
<table class="table table-striped" id="table1" name="datatable">
<thead>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dcdcdc"><input type=checkbox name=select_all value="all"  onclick="CheckAll(this.form)"></td>
</tr>
</thead>
{% if ddatas_perpage %}
<tbody name="datas">
{% for item in ddatas_perpage %}
<tr name="table">
<td><input type=checkbox name=select value={{ item.sn }} ></td>
<td class="text-info" name="tabletd" value={{ item[col] }} ><textarea>{{ item[col] }}</textarea></td>
```

the view_function is:

```
@data.route('/datas/edit/<username>/<tablename>/updatesuccess',methods=['GET','POST'])
def dataupdate(username,tablename):
    selected = request.form.getlist("select")
    ttt = request.form.getlist('datatable')
    tttt = request.form.get('datatable')
    ttttt = request.form.getlist('td')
    tttttt = request.form.get('tablename')
    datas = request.form.get("datas")
    tables = request.form.get("table")
    tabletds = request.args.get("tabletd")

    f = request.form
    flash("#######################",f.keys())
    for key in f.keys():
        flash(key)
        for value in f.getlist(key):
            flash(key+":"+value)
    flash(ttt)
    flash(tttt)
    flash(ttttt)
    flash('############',tttttt)
    flash(selected)
    flash(datas)
    flash(tables)
    flash(tabletds)
    cases = UserCase.query.filter_by(username=username).all()
    session['loginname']=username
    if cases is not None:
        return render_template('data/usercase.html', ccases=cases)
```

when I submit the form,only checkbox can use request.form.getlist("select") get value but other contents in table was None.

why it did not get the table contents but checkbox??
I user request.form.get OR request.args.get get the same result,especially use request.form get keys only contain checkbox keys [select].
I want get the web table contents and update to database table.How can I do in Flask??

Comment: Why would you think those other values would exist? The only actual form elements you have in your template are the checkboxes with name "select".

Comment: When you submit a form, only `input`, `select`, `textarea`, and `button` fields are sent to the server.

Comment: @dirn your comment should be made an answer. It is very helpful and the information is not found everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there aren't any other form inputs excepting checkboxes *you gave a `name` attributes*. If you find yourself wanting to get values from `textarea`s, try specify names on them.